# str_split não funciona bem em string contendo UTF-8?

Tags: php, string

Quero iterar uma string com `foreach`. Para isso, aprendi que devo utilizar a função `str_split`, que separa cada caractere da string para um 
`array`. Porém essa operação não funciona como esperado quando utilizo strings que contenha acentuações, por exemplo (caracteres do utf-8).

Exemplo:

```
str_split('coração da programação');
```

O resultado para isso é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => c
    [1] => o
    [2] => r
    [3] => a
    [4] => �
    [5] => �
    [6] => �
    [7] => �
    [8] => o
    [9] =>  
    [10] => d
    [11] => a
    [12] =>  
    [13] => p
    [14] => r
    [15] => o
    [16] => g
    [17] => r
    [18] => a
    [19] => m
    [20] => a
    [21] => �
    [22] => �
    [23] => �
    [24] => �
    [25] => o
)
```

Como faço para dividir uma string da mesma forma que `str_split` faz, porém mantendo os caracteres `utf-8`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como algumas funções do php não tem suporte a caracteres multibytes, por incrivel que parece a solução é regex O.o, pois nessa biblioteca eles são suportados.

Pode utilizar o meta caracter ponto(`.`) para quebrar a string em um array e obter o mesmo resultado que `str_split()`, vale lembra que para isso é necessário utilizar o modificaro `u` da PCRE.

```
$str = 'ação';
preg_match_all('/./u', $str, $arr);

echo "<pre>";
```

Sáida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => ç
            [2] => ã
            [3] => o
        )

)
```

Comment: Interessante. Eu já pensei em usar `preg_split` com o `.`, mas ele deixa um tanto de espaço. Aí tem que usar `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`. Já com `preg_match` não tem esse problema.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, cada a lib de strings com suporte a unicode? não quero uma tipagem mais rigida na linguagem :P, pq não resolver problemas mais graves antes de ter novos super recursos.

Comment: você quis dizer "cadê". A única coisa que vi que implementaram de utf-8 é o tal dos caracteres especiais. tipo: "Meu nome \x66 wallace".

Answer (score 9):

Como já falaram grande parte das funções padrão de PHP não tem suporte a strings multibyte e para esses casos o ideal é usar as [multibyte string functions](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.mbstring.php). Sendo mais especifico no caso da sua questão o ideal é a [`mb_split`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-split.php).

Comment: Não conhecia `mb_split` +1

Answer (score 2):

O PHP não tem suporte a todos os caracteres unicode, contudo você pode forçá-los através de REGEX.

```
preg_split('//u', 'coração da programação');
```

`u` é o modificador para unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer usando a função [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split).

Uma expressão regular que provê maior compatibilidade é `/(?<!^)(?!$)/u`

```
   $str = 'coração da programação';
   preg_split("/(?<!^)(?!$)/u", $str);
```

## Vou mostrar com as outras respostas são falhas ou inseguras em relação a funcionalidade.

Testando expressões regulares propostas nas outras respostas usando a string `日本語`:

```
   $str = '日本語';
   /*
   Essa é a expressão regular que provê maior segurança
   */
   print_r(preg_split("/(?<!^)(?!$)/u", $str));
   /** 
   retorno:

   Array
   (
       [0] => 日
       [2] => 本
       [3] => 語
   )
   */

   /*
   Essa expressão está numa das respostas (atualmente marcada como aceita)
   */
   print_r(preg_split("/./u", $str));
   /*
   Funciona bem com caracteres romanos, porém, não retorna corretamente com um simples kanji

   Array
   (
       [0] => 
       [1] => 
       [2] => 
       [3] => 
   )
   */

   print_r(preg_split("//u", $str));
   /*
   Essa outra consegue separar os caracteres, porém, retorna índices vazios no começo e no fim.

   Array
   (
       [0] => 
       [1] => 日
       [2] => 本
       [3] => 語
       [4] => 
   )

   Caso queira usar a expressão "//u", deve-se adicionar alguns parâmetros caso não queira os índices com valores vazios:
   */
   print_r(preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
   /**
   Retorno:

   Array
   (
       [0] => 日
       [1] => 本
       [2] => 語
   )
   */
```

## Opcional para controle de quantidade de caracteres:

```
$str = '日本語';

$l = 1;
print_r(preg_split('/(.{'.$l.'})/us', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

Por fim, uma rotina simples, apenas percorrendo cada caracter da string e populando um array:

```
$str = '日本語';
$l = mb_strlen($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    $arr[] = mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
}
print_r($arr);
// Dependendo do caso, esse pode ser mais performático que todos os outros.
// Basta saber como e quando usar os recursos da linguagem.
```

Nota: Os exemplos acima são para ambientes onde o conjunto de caracteres esteja corretamente configurado.

Answer (score 0):

De php.net

```
<?php
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
?>
```