# Problema com caractere especiais com php

Tags: php, html

Tenho esse script que separa uma string por caractere.

```
<?php
    $key = "VÔMITOS";
      for( $i=0; $i < $n_caracteres ; $i++ ){
        print $key[$i]."\n";
      }
    ?>
```

E ele volta o seguinte erro: V � � M I T O.

Já usei os seguintes códigos

No HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

No PHP

```
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Alguém teria uma solução.

Comment: @George `mb_split` deve resolver o seu problema. Veja as respostas desta pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111131/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acabei de usar mais não funcionou

Comment: E tem certeza que usou corretamente? Você tentou `preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)`? Veja que é mais de uma resposta, todas tem explicação, então leia elas e faça os testes com calma e atenção. **Aproveita** e faz a checagem dos detalhes importante para se trabalhar com UTF-8 seguindo as dicas em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635

Comment: além disso tudo que o pessoal já falou aí acima, caso você não queria fazer do jeito deles. Tem que ver se você salvou o documento no formato UTF8 também e se o no Apache/PHP está configurado o charset para UTF8 também.