# Somar caracteres com acentos dentro de um array

Tags: php

Tenho uma variável que armazena um nome:

```
$nome = 'André Ramos';
```

Tenho um *array* que exibe as todas as letras:

```
$letras = array (

            'A' => 1,
            'B' => 2,
            'C' => 3,
            'D' => 4,
            'F' => 8,
            'G' => 3,
            'H' => 5,
            'I' => 1,
            'J' => 1,
            'K' => 2,
            'L' => 3,
            'M' => 4,
            'N' => 5,
            'O' => 7,
            'P' => 8,
            'Q' => 1,
            'R' => 2,
            'S' => 3,
            'T' => 4,
            'U' => 6,
            'V' => 6,
            'X' => 6,
            'W' => 6,
            'Y' => 1,
            'Z' => 7,
            'Á' => 5,
            'É' => 4,
            'Í' => 8,
            'Ó' => 6,
            'Ú' => 3,
            'Ã' => 7,
            'Ñ' => 2

);
```

Quando digitar o nome na variável `$nome` preciso que o *array* `$letras` verifique cada caractere e exiba o valor dele. Precisa exibir o valor de letras com acentuação também.

Por exemplo:

```
$nome: 'André';

array (size=5)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 4
  3 => int 2
  4 => int 4
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Comece estudando a função [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strlen.php)

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SO, por favor faça um [tour] pela plataforma para aprender mais como tirar o melhor proveito e como criar perguntas que possam resultar em ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema consiste, basicamente, em percorrer uma *string* acentuada. O problema é que o PHP, por padrão, irá percorrer os caracteres a cada byte, se perdendo em caracteres multibytes, como no caso das letras acentuadas. Por exemplo, `strlen('andré')` retorna 6 ao invés de 5, pois a letra `é` demanda 2 bytes e a *string* inteira possui 6 bytes ao todo.

Como discutido em:

- [str_split não funciona bem em string contendo UTF-8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111131/5878)

Você pode fazer:

```
$nome = 'andré';

if (preg_match_all('/./u', $nome, $caracteres) !== false) {
    $numeros = array_map(function ($letra) use ($letras) {
        return $letras[mb_strtoupper($letra)];
    }, $caracteres[0]);

    var_export($numeros);
}
```

O resultado será:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 5,
  2 => 4,
  3 => 2,
  4 => 4,
)
```

Documentações das funções para pesquisa:

- [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php)
- [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)
- [`mb_strtoupper`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-strtoupper.php)
- [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-export.php)

Comment: muito obrigado, era exatamente isso que eu procurava. Vou estudar mais a respeito!

Answer (score -2):

Segue a resposta man...

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
    $f_lambda = create_function('$a,$b', 'return array_key_exists($a,$b);');
    $arr_str_acentuados = array('Á' => 0,'É' => 0, 'Í' => 0, 'Ó' => 0, 'Ú' => 0);
    $frase = "É uma fraude! Como é fácil identificar essa coisas! Ótima solução!";
    $str_arr = str_split(mb_strtoupper(utf8_decode($frase),$encoding));

    foreach ($str_arr as $v)
       if($f_lambda(utf8_encode($v),$arr_str_acentuados))
          $arr_str_acentuados[utf8_encode($v)]++;


    print_r($arr_str_acentuados);
 ?>
```

Comment: Poderia explicar a sua solução? Por que usar `create_function`, que é uma função obsoleta a partir do PHP 7.2, para apenas chamar `array_key_exists`? Não é mais fácil chamar a função diretamente?

Comment: Sim, é obsoleto na versão 7 e o manual indica como opção a utilização de Anonymous Functions.

No caso ficaria assim o código:

 $f_lambda = function($a,$b)
 {
  return array_key_exists($a,$b);
 };

Comment: E por que fazer isso? Não é mais simples fazer `if (array_key_exists($a, $b))`?

Comment: Obrigado @CarlosMesquitaAguiar

Comment: Por nada @Js Dev!

Comment: @CarlosMesquitaAguiar, pode tirar outra dúvida?

Comment: @CarlosMesquitaAguiar eu editei a pergunta, na verdade eu preciso de uma outra informação, se conseguir dar uma olhada, obrigado.