# Mostrar valores em um array de acordo com uma variavel

Tags: php

Tenho uma variável que armazena um nome:

```
$nome = 'André Ramos';
```

Tenho um *array* que exibe as todas as letras:

```
$letras = array (

            'A' => 1,
            'B' => 2,
            'C' => 3,
            'D' => 4,
            'F' => 8,
            'G' => 3,
            'H' => 5,
            'I' => 1,
            'J' => 1,
            'K' => 2,
            'L' => 3,
            'M' => 4,
            'N' => 5,
            'O' => 7,
            'P' => 8,
            'Q' => 1,
            'R' => 2,
            'S' => 3,
            'T' => 4,
            'U' => 6,
            'V' => 6,
            'X' => 6,
            'W' => 6,
            'Y' => 1,
            'Z' => 7,
            'Á' => 5,
            'É' => 4,
            'Í' => 8,
            'Ó' => 6,
            'Ú' => 3,
            'Ã' => 7,
            'Ñ' => 2

);
```

Quando digitar o nome na variável `$nome` preciso que o *array* `$letras` verifique cada caractere e exiba o valor dele. Precisa exibir o valor de letras com acentuação também.

Por exemplo:

```
$nome: 'André';

array (size=5)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 4
  3 => int 2
  4 => int 4
```

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Existe alguma relação com [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/352288/5878) ou [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/352069/5878)? Parece ser exatamente a mesma pergunta, só que de outro usuário ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Mesma pergunta. Porém ainda não obtive uma resposta e não consigo mais perguntar no outro usuário.

Comment: Nem editar a pergunta?

Comment: Pergunta editada:

[link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/352069/somar-caracteres-com-acentos-dentro-de-um-array)

Comment: SOLUÇÃO: $caracteres = str_split(utf8_decode($nome)); $numeros = array_map( function($caracter) use ($letras) { $key = utf8_encode(strtoupper($caracter)); return isset($letras[$key]) ? $letras[$key] : "?"; }, $caracteres); $nomeNumeros = implode($numeros); echo $nomeNumeros;